# Println() not printing on a new line? How to fix within my decimal to binary and hex program?

Tags: java

The hex conversion doesn't print on a new line even though it is `System.out.println()`. The binary number from its conversion is just on a `Print()` but that is because my program prints out every single number of the binary number on a new line if I make it to `Println()`. I believe the cause of this is arrays... however i'm only a beginner and i don't know what to do to solve this.

```
public static void conversionTool(){
      System.out.println("Number Conversion Tool");
      System.out.println("----------------------");
      System.out.println("Please enter a positive base 10 number:");

    // Decimal to Binary conversion begins

      int decimalInput = userInput.nextInt();
      int binary[] = new int [32];
      int inDexa = binary.length-1;

      int newName = decimalInput;

      while (decimalInput != 0){
        binary [inDexa] = decimalInput % 2;
        decimalInput = decimalInput/2;
        inDexa--;
      }

        for (int n : binary){
        System.out.print(n);
        }

    // Decimal to Hex conversion begins

      int rem;
      String str = "";
      char hexaDecimal [] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',};

      while (newName != 0){
        rem = newName % 16;
        str = hexaDecimal [rem] + str;
        newName = newName / 16;
      }
      
      System.out.println(" Hex: " + str);
      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

the last `System.out.println()` will add a new line at the end of print but you need before printing of the line, so use this way:

```
for (int n : binary){
   System.out.print(n);
}
System.out.println(); //We don't need quotes here
```

**or**

```
System.out.println("\n Hex: " + str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Number Conversion Tool");
  System.out.println("----------------------");
  System.out.println("Please enter a positive base 10 number:");

// Decimal to Binary conversion begins

  int decimalInput = userInput.nextInt();
  int binary[] = new int [32];
  int inDexa = binary.length-1;

  int newName = decimalInput;

  while (decimalInput != 0){
    binary [inDexa] = decimalInput % 2;
    decimalInput = decimalInput/2;
    inDexa--;
  }
    System.out.print("Binary : ");
    for (int n : binary){
    System.out.print(n);
    }
    System.out.println();
// Decimal to Hex conversion begins

  int rem;
  String str = "";
  char hexaDecimal [] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',};

  while (newName != 0){
    rem = newName % 16;
    str = hexaDecimal [rem] + str;
    newName = newName / 16;
  }
  
  System.out.println("Hex : " + str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        conversionTool(scan);
    }

    public static void conversionTool(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Number Conversion Tool");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive base 10 number: ");

        int decimalInput = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("bin: b" + toBinaryString(decimalInput));
        System.out.println("hex: 0x" + toHexString(decimalInput));
    }

    private static String toBinaryString(int val) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(32);

        while (val != 0) {
            buf.append(val % 2);
            val /= 2;
        }

        return buf.reverse().toString();
//        return Integer.toBinaryString(val);
    }

    private static final char[] HEX = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', };

    private static String toHexString(int val) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        while (val != 0) {
            buf.append(HEX[val % 16]);
            val /= 16;
        }

        return buf.reverse().toString();
//        return Integer.toHexString(val);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Number Conversion Tool
----------------------
Please enter a positive base 10 number: 12358
bin: b11000001000110
hex: 0x3046
```